# unpack-objects failed when fetching big files

Tags: git

I keep getting this error when fetching from a remote. It only happens when there's some big file to download (in this case it's about a 500KB file):

```
> git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 20, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

Before failing the last thing I can see is this (where it gets stuck):

```
Unpacking objects:  75% (15/20)
```

I've tried to set `core.compression` to 0 and -1, none helped. I've also set both `http.postbuffer` and `ssh.postbuffer` to huge numbers, but it didn't help either. I've got a feeling is a problem with the network, but can't figure out exactly what it is.

Comment: What version of Git do you have, what's the server version, and what OS? There were some recent fixes to some 32bit limitations recently. Perhaps browse the new git list that has replaced gmane at http://public-inbox.org/git/

Comment: Git version 2.10.0, running on a Mac OSX 10.11.6 (15G31). Seems to be working fine again now. I'm thinking could have been some problem with BitBucket itself?

Comment: It certainly sound like it could have been a hiccup at the server/network level, especially if everything is now working OK.